# How to be able to manually run jenkins build for a branch while automatically running for all branches?

Tags: git, jenkins

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32892211/how-can-i-trigger-a-manual-build-in-jenkins-when-i-have-polling-enabled-for-all but in my case I'm not polling, I'm using webhooks to trigger the build.

Sometimes a build has a transient failure, or for some reason the webhook doesn't trigger a build when it's supposed to.

How can I manually run it for a specific branch while leaving it with only one build that runs automatically on all of them?

I can workaround this by adding empty commits (`git commit --allow-empty`) to bump the automatic trigger but I'd like a solution where I can just use the "build now" button.

Comment: Are you using Atlassian Stash to host your Git repositories?

Comment: @BrunoLavit I'm using Github

Comment: OK thanks for the update, I don't have a solution for Github for the moment.

Comment: @BrunoLavit still worth posting an answer for other people in a similar situation

Comment: OK, no problem: I'll post the solution for the people using Atlassian Stash.

Comment: Sorry my solution works only for PR opened on specific branches :( If you want to trigger a build only for a branch (without a PR), I don't have a solution except the one your proposed (with the empty commits).